# Is there a way to set only defined properties when using fetch_object on a mysqli_result?

Tags: php, mysqli

If I have a class:

```
class ExampleClass {
    private $thing1;
    private $thing2;
}
```

I can use `fetch_object('ExampleClass')` on a mysqli_result object to create an instance of ExampleClass. Using this method, the private properties of ExampleClass will be set, provided the query has columns with the same names.

In addition to those properties, other public properties will be added for any other columns in the query. Is there any way to avoid this?  I couldn't find anything about it in the [php documentation for fetch_object](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php).

If I set up ExampleClass with a constructor like this

```
function __construct($properties = []) {
    foreach ($properties as $key => $value)
        if (property_exists($this, $key))
            $this->$key = $value;
}
```

I can get the row from the result set using fetch_assoc instead of fetch_object, and then create a new ExampleClass with the resulting array as an argument.  This achieves what I am going for, but I was hoping for something more direct.

Comment: Why _would_ you have fields in the resultset you don't want? Make the query suit the need seems the easiest solution for this...

Comment: I can't remember why I was trying to do this.

Answer (score 0):

For one of my projects I have built a system just like that.
All classes are derived of the basic abstract Object class which, among others, offers a `cloneInstance()` method. Then, in the concrete implementing class, I'm simply going to use it ('I'm assuming that $pdo is somehow accessible here, for brevity):

Note that `cloneInstance()` uses reflection to check if the target instance actually has a euqlly named property (`$drfl->hasProperty()`).

```
abstract class Object {

    protected function cloneInstance($obj) {
        if (is_object($obj)) {
            $srfl = new ReflectionObject($obj);
            $drfl = new ReflectionObject($this);
            $sprops = $srfl->getProperties();
            foreach ($sprops as $sprop) {
                $sprop->setAccessible(true);
                $name = $sprop->getName();
                if ($drfl->hasProperty($name)) {
                    $value = $sprop->getValue($obj);
                    $propDest = $drfl->getProperty($name);
                    $propDest->setAccessible(true);
                    $propDest->setValue($this,$value);
                }
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }


class MyAutomaticClass extends Object {
    // static loader
    public static function load($id) {
        $result = null;
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id=:id';
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql, array(':id' => $id));
        $list = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        if (count($list)) {
            $result = new MyAutomaticClass($list[0]);
        }
        return $result;
    }

    // constructor makes use of base Objects cloning feature
    public function __construct($obj=null) {
        if (is_object($obj)) {
            $this->cloneInstance($obj);
        }
    }
}
```